# How do I import a jsonl file in R and how do I transform it in csv?

Tags: json, r, csv

For my PhD project I need to read a JSONL file into R (the extension isn't json, is jsonl) and transform it in a csv.
I tried to use this code based on jsonlite but it gives me an error:

```
library(jsonlite)
data <- "/Users/chiarap/tweets.jsonl"
dat <- fromJSON(sprintf("[%s]", paste(readLines(data), collapse=",")))
Error: parse error: unallowed token at this point in JSON text
          EFEF","notifications":null}},,,{"in_reply_to_status_id_str":
                     (right here) ------^
```

Thanks

Comment: First time I heard of `jsonl`, but I guess that are just standard `json` in which each line is a different `json`. Try to call `fromJSON` for each line of the file. For instance `content<-readLines(data)` and then `fromJSON(content[i])` where `i` ranges between 1 and the number of rows in the file.

Comment: @nicola thank you very much, it works. Before writing here I tried to use the readLines function combined with fromJSON but I couldn’t find any example of how to write correctly the script. This was very helpful.

Answer (score 9):

If you have a large file, pasting all of the rows together may result in errors.  You can process each line separately and then combine them into a data frame.

```
library(jsonlite)
library(dplyr)

lines <- readLines("myfile.jsonl")
lines <- lapply(lines, fromJSON)
lines <- lapply(lines, unlist)
x <- bind_rows(lines)
```

Then x is a data frame that you can continue to work with or write to file.