# How to import large JSONL files to R

Tags: r, json, large-files

I am trying to read large (>10gb) JSONL files in R, but I am getting an error message when I use the fromJSON function:

> library(rjson)

> data = "D:/Data/2020-02-01_tweets.jsonl"

> result <- fromJSON(file=data)

> Error in paste(readLines(file, warn = FALSE), collapse = "") :
> result would exceed 2^31-1 bytes

I did some research and it turns out JSONL files are different from regular JSON ones in the sense that each entry in the JSONL is valid JSON. How should I go about importing these files? I have 32gb of ram so size shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: try using `library(jsonlite)`.  See this answer for large jsonl import guidance: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62311093/2070999

Comment: `jsonlite::stream_in(file("D:/Data/2020-02-01_tweets.jsonl"))`

Comment: could someone post this information as an answer?