# Write json scalars in R

Tags: r, jsonlite

In [r](/questions/tagged/r), I have some data in a data frame and need to export it to `jsonl`. In `jsonl` [each line is its own valid json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35016713/how-do-i-import-a-jsonl-file-in-r-and-how-do-i-transform-it-in-csv/62311093#62311093). As the linked question shows, you can easily do that by applying `jsonlite::toJSON()` to each row. My problem is that I need one of the variables to be a scalar string, but `toJSON` makes any vector R vector into a list:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(jsonlite)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'jsonlite'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:purrr':
#> 
#>     flatten
d <- tibble(
  id = 1:3,
  text = c("this is a string", "this is another string", "yet another string")
) 

jl <- d |> 
  transpose() |> 
  map_chr(toJSON) 

jl
#> [1] "{\"id\":[1],\"text\":[\"this is a string\"]}"      
#> [2] "{\"id\":[2],\"text\":[\"this is another string\"]}"
#> [3] "{\"id\":[3],\"text\":[\"yet another string\"]}"
```

I need `text` to be scalar. Desired output:

```r
#> [1] "{\"id\":[1],\"text\":\"this is a string\"}"      
#> [2] "{\"id\":[2],\"text\":\"this is another string\"}"
#> [3] "{\"id\":[3],\"text\":\"yet another string\"}"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We may use `auto_unbox = TRUE`

```
library(purrr)
library(jsonlite)
d |> 
  transpose() |> 
  map_chr(toJSON, auto_unbox = TRUE)
```

-output

```
[1] "{\"id\":1,\"text\":\"this is a string\"}" 
[2] "{\"id\":2,\"text\":\"this is another string\"}"
[3] "{\"id\":3,\"text\":\"yet another string\"}"
```